# Unity 8 lxc stucks after login. Unity 8 mir black screen without sursor

Tags: unity, login, lxc, mir, unity8

I installed Unity 8 mir and unity 8 lxc on Ubuntu 16.04,

When log to unity 8 mir, a black screen displayed (without cursor).
When log to Unity 8 lxc, It stucks at the loin screen (LightDM).

Then I go press "alt+ctrl+F1", and run the command `startx` , then I can log to both mir and lxc environments. But it haveng the background and the cursor only. Can "right click" using the cursor. There's no launcher and the top pannel.

(I'm using open source graphics drivers)

How to fix this ?

Please help me. I need to use Unity 8.

Thanks. Sorry for my weak English. English is my second language.